# SQL View to join two tables that have no link

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

With PeriodID, fromDate, ToDate.... Then I have another one called "Transaction"

with txId, txDate, Debit, Credit... these tables are ready made for a certain program and I can't change them.

So I want to know if there is a way to search the period table using the txDate from Transaction, then if the txDate is between the fromDate and toDate of a certain Period I want a view that combines the Transaction take and just adds The PeriodID.

Comment: Please provide sample data of both tables and the desired outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data, it is always a little hard to answer these questions.  But assuming I've correctly understood you...

You can use [between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to join these two tables.

This join will return the period that covers the transaction date.

```
-- Join without a matching field.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Transaction] AS t
        INNER JOIN [Period] AS p        ON t.txDate BETWEEN p.fromDate AND p.toDate
;
```

Comment: Yes you have understood me correctly, this is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Is it adapted for your question ?

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM Period WHERE txDate BETWEEN fromDate AND ToDate
)
```

Comment: Be careful when referencing an outer query from a subquery.  This is called a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).  These types of queries can reduce performance because SQL Server is forced to re-evaluate the subquery once for every row returned by the outer query.